Data treatment for long-term mark-recapture study
I am looking to calculate population estimates for two species at a site where mark-recapture work has been conducted since 2010. Due to the long-term nature of the study, I an open population model will need to be used to account for mortality, recruitment, etc. over the years. Hundreds of individuals have been captured and the recapture rate for both species is >10%.
However, capture work was not conducted at the same time(s) every year, and effort during those visits also varied. For example, in early years the site was visited multiple times during the spring and autumn, there are two years where the site was not visited at all, and in later years the site was only visited one to three times at different times of year. I'm looking for advice on how I should divide this data into discrete survey events (ex. by visit, by month, by season, by year) for as accurate a population estimate as possible and how best to take into account the varying effort each year depending on how survey events are distinguished.

Jolly-Seber models can estimate return rates and survival rates that vary between survey intervals, which would accommodate the different seasons, intervals, and effort of the surveys. I think this would let you simply divide the data by visit?
